# Is it possible to gain a bigger optimization boost for the following batch+bulk INSERT approach for SQLIte in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, optimization, bulkinsert

I'm developing a cross-platform data importer and I'm currently trying to optimize the overall import performance on both JRE and Android runtimes.
Having JDBC in use, I managed to optimize the importer on test data (~500K rows if I'm not mistaken) for the JRE runtime from 12s to 3,5s-4s just using JDBC `addBatch` and `executeBatch` with all done in a single transaction. 
Now, I'm trying to port some of the components to the Android runtime, and I'm facing with much worse performance.
I've read a lot of related questions on the S.O. and articles in the Internet, but I'm not really sure whether what I'm doing for Android is right.
The following pseudo-demo approach gained some performance boost from about 119-120s to 59-61s on my mobile device (caching compiled statements, batching, and generating bulk `INSERT` statements).
So, here is the simplified version of the prototype (there might be mistakes when converting from the prototype to the pseudo-demo code):

```java
final class Test {

    private Test() {
    }

    // SQLite meta stuff

    private static final int MAX_SQLITE_VARS_PER_STATEMENT = 999;

    // Application core

    private static final class Foo {
    }

    private static final class Bar {
    }

    // SQL stuff

    private static final int FOO_TUPLE_SIZE = 8;
    private static final int BAR_TUPLE_SIZE = 4;

    private static final Joiner commaJoiner = Joiner.on(',');

    private static SQLiteStatement compileStatement(final Class<?> clazz, final int bulkCount, final SQLiteDatabase database) {
        final String statementPattern;
        final String variableTuple;
        final int variableCount;
        if ( clazz == Foo.class ) {
            statementPattern = "INSERT INTO foos(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8)VALUES %s;";
            variableTuple = "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            variableCount = FOO_TUPLE_SIZE;
        } else if ( clazz == Bar.class ) {
            statementPattern = "INSERT INTO bars(c1,c2,c3,c4)VALUES %s;";
            variableTuple = "(?,?,?,?)";
            variableCount = BAR_TUPLE_SIZE;
        } else {
            throw new AssertionError(clazz);
        }
        if ( bulkCount * variableCount > MAX_SQLITE_VARS_PER_STATEMENT ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Too many variables");
        }
        final String joinedTuples = commaJoiner.join(Iterables.limit(Iterables.cycle(variableTuple), bulkCount));
        final String statement = String.format(statementPattern, joinedTuples);
        return database.compileStatement(statement);
    }

    private static SQLiteStatement bindFoosStatement(final Collection<Foo> foos) {
        final SQLiteStatement statement = statementCache.getUnchecked(new BulkKey(Foo.class, foos.size()));
        int i = 0;
        for ( final Foo foo : foos ) {
            // bind all variables:
            // * bind variable 1 (and then 9, 17, 25...)
            // * bind variable 2 (and then 10, 18, 26...)
            // ...
            // * bind variable 8 (and then 16, 24, 32...)
            i += FOO_TUPLE_SIZE;
        }
        return statement;
    }

    private static SQLiteStatement bindBarsStatement(final Collection<Bar> bars) {
        final SQLiteStatement statement = statementCache.getUnchecked(new BulkKey(Bar.class, bars.size()));
        int i = 0;
        for ( final Bar bar : bars ) {
            // bind all variables:
            // * bind variable 1 (and then 5, 9, 13...)
            // * bind variable 2 (and then 6, 10, 14...)
            // ...
            // * bind variable 4 (and then 8, 12, 16...)
            i += BAR_TUPLE_SIZE;
        }
        return statement;
    }

    // Statements caching

    @EqualsAndHashCode
    private static final class BulkKey {

        private final Class<?> clazz;
        private final int count;

        private BulkKey(final Class<?> clazz, final int count) {
            this.clazz = clazz;
            this.count = count;
        }

    }

    private static final LoadingCache<BulkKey, SQLiteStatement> statementCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .removalListener((RemovalListener<BulkKey, SQLiteStatement>) notification -> notification.getValue().close())
            .build(new CacheLoader<BulkKey, SQLiteStatement>() {
                @Override
                public SQLiteStatement load(final BulkKey bulkKey) {
                    return compileStatement(bulkKey.clazz, bulkKey.count, sqliteDatabase);
                }
            });

    // Application

    private static final SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = null; // dummy
    private static final List<Foo> foos = ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.limit(Iterables.cycle(new Foo()), 10000));
    private static final List<Bar> bars = ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.limit(Iterables.cycle(new Bar()), 4500));

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        // The following code is a very simplified version of the prototype
        // The prototype is written in reactive manner and the code below just mimics the batching
        // Initialize the import operation
        final List<List<Foo>> type1Batches = Lists.partition(foos, MAX_SQLITE_VARS_PER_STATEMENT / FOO_TUPLE_SIZE); // = 124
        sqliteDatabase.beginTransaction();
        for ( final List<Foo> batch : type1Batches ) {
            final SQLiteStatement statement = bindFoosStatement(batch);
            statement.executeInsert();
            statement.clearBindings();
        }
        final List<List<Bar>> type2Batches = Lists.partition(bars, MAX_SQLITE_VARS_PER_STATEMENT / BAR_TUPLE_SIZE); // = 249
        for ( final List<Bar> batch : type2Batches ) {
            final SQLiteStatement statement = bindBarsStatement(batch);
            statement.executeInsert();
            statement.clearBindings();
        }
        // Finalize the import operation
        sqliteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
        sqliteDatabase.endTransaction();
        statementCache.invalidateAll();
    }

}
```

The above approach tries to use convert batches to bulk `INSERT` statements depending on the batch size and number of variables in the specified class tuple object not exceeding the SQLite limit of 999 variables per a statement.

I'm wondering, what am I missing so I could gain some more performance boost, or is it just close to the limits so no optimization further? Thanks.